# SQL select case as

Tags: mysql, sql, database, plsql

I'm writing a sql statment. It looks like this

```
select case when c.used = 1 then 'Used'
            else 'Unused'
       end
from my_table
```

How can I name the col with the `as` keyword. I tried it after the string and after the `end`. Nothing works.

Please help me. Thank you :)

Comment: Hint:  `end as colname`

Comment: What happens when you put it after the `end`?

Comment: You said you tried putting the `AS` keyword after `END` and it didn't work. But that's what the accepted answer does. Can you show what you tried that didn't work, so we can see the difference?

Comment: What does Oracle PL/SQL have to do with this MySQL syntax question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use backticks to quote reserved word:

```
select case when c.used = 1 then 'Used'
            else 'Unused'
       end AS `as`
from my_table;
```

Optionally using `""`:

```
SELECT 1 AS `as`, 2 AS "as"
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ad8e2dc49c575fe223c874916544295c)**

Comment: @RaymondNijland `AS` is a keyword. `'Used'/'unused'` are string literals not identifiers.

Comment: "AS is a keyword. 'Used'/'unused' are string literals not identifiers. " Nevermind didn't say annything didn't read properly